# How copy files recursively to another folder but without copying the source folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that copies files from one folder to another recursively depending on extensions and it works fine until Dst is in Src. Let me explain:

If I send .txt files to a subfolder that is in Src, the subfolder will copy itself. is there any way to prevent this from happening? I have tried with a break but it does not copy all the files because when the source_fn condition is met, the function stops. When source_fn == Dst is not met the script copies Dst back into itself. I know it sounds a bit confusing and I hope you can help me.

This is what Src looks like:

```
My documents
--- file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
--- Text_files (subfolder) Dst
```

This is how it currently works if I want the script to copy from Src (My Documents) only the .txt files to Dst (Text_Files) recursively maintaining the folder hierarchy:

```
My documents
--- file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
--- Text_files (subfolder) Dst
    ---file.txt
    ---Text_files (Subfolder)
       --- folder (subfolder)
           --- file2.txt
       ---file.txt
       --- folder (subfolder)
           --- file2.txt
```

As it should look:

```
My documents (Src)
---file.txt
--- Text_files (Subfolder) Dst
      ---file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
```

script:

```
import os
import winshell

def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions)

        try:

            extensions = .txt .png

            for item in os.listdir(Src):
                source_fn = os.path.join(Src, item)

                if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                    copywf1(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), 
                    extensions, overwriten)

                elif os.path.splitext(item)[1] in extensions:

                    if not os.path.exists(Dst):
                        os.makedirs(Dst)

                        winshell.copy_file(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), 
                        allow_undo=True, no_confirm=False, rename_on_collision=True, 
                        silent=False, hWnd=None)

        except winshell.x_winshell:
            pass
```

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to make it work to some extent, now I don't create second level folders, I just copy the first level subfolders. I have tried to place

```
if not os.path.exists(Dst):
     os.makedirs(Dst)
```

In different places but it has no effect.

```
import os
import shutil


def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions):

    try:

        for item in os.listdir(Src):
            source_fn = os.path.join(Src, item)
            print(source_fn, Dst)

            if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                split_dst = os.path.normpath(Dst).split(os.sep)
                if not all([path in split_dst for  path in os.path.normpath(source_fn).split(os.sep)]):
                    copywf1(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), extensions)

            elif os.path.splitext(item)[1] in extensions:

                if not os.path.exists(Dst):
                    os.makedirs(Dst)

                shutil.copyfile(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

copywf1(r"SRC", r"DST", ".extension")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I know it sounds a bit confusing and I hope you can help me." That [isn't answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), but I can at least explain [ask] more clearly. Can you show an example of: **what is in the source folder** when a problem occurs, and **what is in the dst folder, before copying**; then explain **what should happen** (i.e., what should the `dst` folder look like afterwards) and **what happens instead** (what goes wrong? Is it caught in a loop? Are there wrong files? Files in the wrong places? An error message? Something else?)

Comment: You are right, I have edited my post to be clearer and more precise.

Comment: For better portability use the *os* module rather than *winshell*.  The code shown is not runnable due to a syntax error

Comment: Ah, so the problem is because `Dst` is **already inside of** `Src`? I see that the code is already manually using recursion in order to traverse the directory tree. Did you consider writing code to **check** if the folder that will be recursed into, is the same as the destination folder, and skipping it if so?

Comment: The problem is that if Dst is a subfolder of Src, it copies itself, it does not do it indefinitely, but as I put in the example, it does it at least once. The idea is that it does not copy itself.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions)
        try:
            extensions = .txt .png
```

Yeah, that's not going to work, is it?

Assign a set, rather than a syntax error:

```
            extensions = {'.txt', '.png'}
```

And use a shorter signature -- no point in asking
the caller to pass it in if you're going to unconditionally
overwrite it.

You can [retrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) a given file's extension with

```
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
```

and then ask

```
            if ext in extensions:
```

to conditionally copy desired file types.

---

Your code features a recursive call:

```
                if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                    copywf1( ... )
```

Great, more power to you! If you can make it work.
It isn't obvious to me that it does.
I haven't puzzled out the path length invariant that it maintains.
Also, your code passes 4 args but the signature accepts just 3.

Here is a simpler approach, using the standard [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)
which recurses down the tree for you:

```
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Src):
            ...
```

---

spelling nit: [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) asks that you downcase it: `src`

---

When you get this working to your satisfaction,
please [do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) post the final code.

Answer (score 0):

*If I send .txt files to a subfolder that is in Src, the subfolder will copy itself. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?*

There is a way to resolve such kind of problems by thinking a bit "out of the box". Instead of searching for a way around the detected problem change the used method. For example by splitting the part searching for files which should be copied from the part actually copying them approaching it for example like this:

- first collect paths to all the files you want to copy in a list
- then loop over all elements of the list created before to actually copy the files

Splitting the task into these two steps helps to avoid potential problems with a destination folder within the folder tree from which files are copied. If there are already files in the destination folder and you haven't filtered them out in the first step you can in an intermediate step between the first and the second step remove from the list all of the files below the path to the destination folder.

Generally said: **Avoid changes by deletion or addition of items in the structure (like a file system or a Python list or other kind of objects holding multiple items) you are traversing or going over in a loop or by recursion.**

It will help you in the future to avoid this kind of problems like this one you just had run into.

Below a suggestion of how coding the task in two steps can look like:

```
# First Step: 
def osWalkFiles(fullPathDir, fileExtensions=("",)):
    import os
    files = []
    osWalkLLists = [
        [ os.path.join(root, fname) 
              for fname in files if fname.endswith(fileExtensions) ] 
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fullPathDir) ]
    for item in osWalkLLists: files += item
    return files
#:def
fileExtensions = (".png", ".txt")
lstFiles = osWalkFiles(fullPathSrcDir, fileExtensions)


# Intermediate Step (filters out files in destination folder): 
lstFiles = [ file for file in lstFiles if fullPathTgtDir not in file ] 


# Second step: 
def shutilCpyFiles(lstFullPathFileNames, fullPathSrcDir, fullPathTgtDir):
    import os
    import shutil
    for srcFileName in lstFullPathFileNames:
        assert fullPathSrcDir in srcFileName
        tgtFileName = srcFileName.replace(fullPathSrcDir, fullPathTgtDir)
        try: 
            shutil.copyfile(srcFileName, tgtFileName)
            print(f'copyfile {srcFileName=} to \n         {tgtFileName=}')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f'creating directory {os.path.split(tgtFileName)[0]}')
            os.mkdir(os.path.split(tgtFileName)[0])
            shutil.copyfile(srcFileName, tgtFileName)
            print(f'copyfile {srcFileName=} to \n         {tgtFileName}=')
#:def
shutilCpyFiles(lstFiles, fullPathSrcDir, fullPathTgtDir)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried a different approach because no matter how hard I tried, I could not get your script to replace the files normally if they already existed because the copying problem reappeared. I tried a different approach but I don't think so and it copies files to a second level of folders. I have updated my question based on this answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What exactly does not work as expected while using the approach in my answer?

Comment: If I run your script twice, it replaces the existing files in DST but the main problem for which I created this question occurs again. You can try it yourself.

Comment: See my updated answer which does not have this problem. It excludes from list of files all these which are within the target directory. I thought that you will manage it by yourself because of the hint in my answer: *If there are already files in the destination folder and you haven't filtered them out in the first step you can in an intermediate step between the first and the second step remove from the list all of the files below the path to the destination folder.* . The updated suggested code does that.